# Lion Server WebDAV not working

Tags: osx-server, webdav

I setup a new lion server, with fully functional dns. Forward and reverse work without issue. I have a forward DNS entry for the server externally. OD is running, and there's 5 network users. Also, all the correct ports are forwarded on the firewall.

AFP works Flawlessly for all users internally and externally, and when the admin logs  into the server with WebDAV, it works fine. Using finder, we use this method: http://server.abc.com/webdav

However, the network users can NOT connect, but the local accounts can. Does anyone have any clue? Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a [blog post](http://thefragens.com/blog/2011/03/setting-up-webdav-share-in-mac-os-x-server/) on how to do this.

1. From Server Admin, make new Web > Realm and set appropriate ACLs.
2. Create a folder in location/volume where data for Share is physically located.
3. Change permissions of folder to _www:admin (that’s what works for me)

   `$ sudo chown _www:admin /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/host.domain.tld`
4. Create a symlink to the share folder in the folder where your web server looks to for the domain’s data.

   `$ sudo ln -s /path/to/data /Library/WebServer/Documents/site_web_folder`

I know there probably a bit of information missing and if I showed images of the actual steps it might make things a bit clearer but I’m a little paranoid about my server and I don’t want to risk opening it up to further attack.

All this needs to be done before OS X will allow a "Connect to Server..." and mount your WebDAV share.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for quite a while to find the answer to this.  Finally found an article on the apple site that is EXACTLY the answer.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4777#

Some additional hints:
For ease, enable the root user on your server and then login as root before you begin.  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528

Also, make sure to use a command line editor OR change the prefs in TextEdit to ensure the files are saved correctly.

Finally, to find the files in the first place you will have to make hidden files visible.http://guides.macrumors.com/Viewing_hidden_files_on_a_Mac